# Broken layout on open bounty notification

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

The bottom padding of the open bounty notification seems to be a bit off to me. If there are no comments, the "add a comment" link overlaps with the bounty div, especially on hover. WIth comments it seems to be barely OK. At the moment you can see an example here: [What is the default chinese font on Android?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/79230)

Here's a screenshot:
[image: Screenshot]

Tested with OSX Chrome 36.0.1985.125 and Safari 7.0.5

Comment: I see the same on Chrome 36.0.1985.143 on Windows 8.1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This will be fixed in the next build, which should be in the next 8 hours.